# Is there a word or phrase defining a bad faith argument that something is not worth doing?

Tags: phrase-requests

I feel like there is a logical fallacy or bad faith argument for a claim that something is pointless, worthless, or has no effect:

"Contact your congresspeople!"

"There's no point.  It doesn't do anything."

I'm having trouble locating the actual term, though.

Comment: [defeatism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defeatism)?

Comment: @HBruijn Yeah, that's probably the best term for what I'm looking for.  Feel free to submit it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: *cynical? fatalistic? **non-constructive**?*

Comment: There is no *argument* in that exchange of dialogue (there is simply an *assertion*), so there can't be a fallacy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Defeatism**

> [[Merriam Webster]](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/defeatism)
>
> - an attitude of accepting, expecting, or being resigned to defeat

Or somewhat related **fatalism**

> [[Merriam Webster]](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fatalism)
>
> - (belief in) a doctrine that events are fixed in advance so that human beings are powerless to change them

Answer (score 2):

**Negativism** seems like a good fit.

> - "The practice or habit of being skeptical, critical, or pessimistic, especially toward the views or suggestions of others." [**TFD**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/negativism)
> - "An attitude of mind marked by skepticism especially about nearly everything affirmed by others" [**MW**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/negativism)

- negativist (noun)
- negativistic (adj) e.g. a negativistic behaviour

Answer (score 0):

*"To contact our congress people' is **fallacious**!"*

**fallacious** [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/fallacious)
adj

> 3. delusive or disappointing; unsoundly or defectively reasoned or argued: *a fallacious hope*.

Answer (score 0):

**empty suggestions**

I would suggest using the word "empty" - I do not think there is any idiomatic phrase.

An "empty" proposal would have a different ring than "futile"  - suggesting more "bad faith"

> **empty** https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/empty
>   ADJECTIVE
>
> 1Containing nothing; not filled or occupied. ‘she put down her empty cup’
>   ‘the room was empty of furniture’
>
> **2) (of words or a gesture) lacking meaning or sincerity.**
>
> ‘their promises were empty words’
>
> 3) Having no value or purpose.

so perhaps:

**"empty proposals"** might be another choice